# Can't get post data from angular in php

Tags: javascript, php, angular, post

I can't solve my problem in my Angular App. I have tried so much, but I can't readout the body of the post data, which are sent from Angular 4. Maybe someone can find the problmen? Would be so nice!

There is a service, which sends data to my PHP-Api. The relevant function looks like this:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserDto> {

    let apiUrl = 'api/v1/login';
    let userAuthDto: UserAuthDto = new UserAuthDto(email, password); 

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(apiUrl, { email, password }, options)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .map(res => console.log(res))
                    .map((data: any) => UserDto.fromJson(data[0]))
                    .do(res => { if (res.auth_success) {
                        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.token);
                    }})
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The relevant code from my API looks like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

//Get database connection
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "******", "********", "*******");
if(!$db) {
    exit("Alert: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Set connection charset to UTF-8
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$test = $data;
$resultArray = array();

$sqlQuery = "SELECT id, username FROM user WHERE id = 4";

//Database query
$myresult = mysqli_query($db, $sqlQuery);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myresult))
{
    $row['auth_success'] = true;
    $row['test'] = $test;
    $resultArray[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

That's just for testing. But the problem is whatever i do `file_get_contents('php://input');` is an empty string. Do you know what's the problem? I'm using XAMPP.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah! I got it!**

After 3 days trying to solve that shit, I got it! Maybe someone has the same problem, so hopefully I can help you:

The problem was **one single** character.

Just changed the API-Url from:

```
let apiUrl = 'api/v1/login';
```

to

```
let apiUrl = 'api/v1/login/';
```

...and everything works!